# Adding Dynamically created div data to a new empty variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I am trying to push the data of a dynamically created div 
`<div id="paging_inner"></div>` to the newly created variable 
`var content= '';`. I commented the code which I tried there in my script.

Is there any jQuery method for inserting the data (without using the jQuery `.append()` method)?

This is what I tried, but I need help:

http://jsfiddle.net/QNZDX/19/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean:

```
var div=$('<div id="paging_inner"></div>');
for(...) {
...
}
$('#paging').html(div);
```

One option would be , creating content inside for loop adding it to a variable, and appending it to the div, after loop, like:

```
var div=$('<div id="paging_inner"></div>');
var insertContent = '';
for(i=0;i<maximages;i++) {
  insertContent += '<a id="page_'+(i+1)+'" data-index="'+(i+1)+'"><span></span></a>';
}
$('div').append(insertContent);
```

Comment: Here also can I use any other thing instead of append `div.append($('<a id="page_'+(i+1)+'" data-index="'+(i+1)+'"><span></span></a>'));`

Comment: This is the updated demo its not working, http://jsfiddle.net/QNZDX/21/ Can you modify this fiddle

Comment: http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqp9c/42 This is the new demo that I am trying can you change in this fiddle, rather than the old one

Answer (score 0):

Or did you mean that you want to move the content of the DIV into a variable called content?

If so, you just do this:

```
var content = document.getElementById("paging_inner").innerHTML;
```